# What is the size of the Android System app?

Tags: applications, system

On my phone the Android System app is zero in size.
Is this normal or have I been hacked?

Thanks, J

Comment: Which system app? System apps are those apps which are installed out of the box and removing/uninstalling may cause errors on future operations. ex: phone, google etc.

Comment: Android System is not an app, it's the whole system itself. But if you are talking about an installed `Android System.apk` it could be a problem (potential threat).

Answer (score 1):

Android System App is only there to represent the Android Framework. If your device is working, you don't have a reason to worry about that.

If that "App" was really of zero size your phone would not even work up until the point that you could actually see its size (= Android would not boot)

Whether you have been hacked is quite a different story, we can't determine that just out of knowing that it shows zero size for you on Android System.